# I'm trying to access video chatting in ios but I'm getting the folling error:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTPublisher", referenced from" can anyone help me out?

Tags: ios

This is my error::

> ignoring file
>   /Users/iton/Desktop/WebRtc/WebRtc/Opentok.framework/Opentok, missing
>   required architecture i386 in file
>   /Users/iton/Desktop/WebRtc/WebRtc/Opentok.framework/Opentok (2 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTPublisher", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTSession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OTSubscriber", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You're referencing classes that aren't being linked into your project.  It seems to be saying that the Opentok framework is not built for the same kind of target (simulator?) that you're trying to use.

Comment: Hai Did you get any solution for this? if yes can you please post me the code...

Answer (score 5):

It looks like that you are trying to run an application with the OpenTok libraries in the local simulator.
Unfortunately, this is not possible as the OpenTok library do not provide an x86 version of their runtime libraries.

For this reason you need to use a real, physical device even for test

Comment: Is there not a way to have it skip the OpenTok framework during compile to the simulator so that we can test on multiple devices via the simulator? I want to test my app on iphones 4, 5, and soon 6 without having to buy each type of phone.